# LaTeX/Special Characters with natbib

Tags: natbib, accents, tilde

I'm trying to reference a source with the authors name including a tilde and a accent:
Castañón

When I put the following line as text it works but when I use the same line in my myreferences.bib (natbib) it will not put the tilde on the n and add a space instead. I added a picture to show the problem.

casta~{n}'{o}n

[image: difference in text and bib reference]

There probably is a simple solution to this but I just cannot seem to figure it out.

Thanks.

Solved:
As one of the comments suggested the problem was a duplicate of another question. By expanding the curved brackets the desired result is reached, the new line looks like this:

```
casta{\~n}\'{o}n
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Please put some more code, which we can copy and compile, and shows your effect. Thanks. Will speed up answers.

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361) (otherwise the backslashes will not render correctly on the site.)

Comment: `Casta{\~n}{\'o}n`